# Delete data in XML with C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML File:

```
 <order id="1234">
      <users>
        <user id="102030" nick="nickname" done="false" />
        <user id="123456" nick="nickname" done="false" />
      </users>
      <machines>
        <machine id="123" sd="123" ref="" done="false" />
        <machine id="456" sd="456" ref="" done="false" />
        <machine id="789" sd="789" ref="" done="false" />
      </machines>
    </order>
```

I want to delete the user with the id 102030, so the xml looks like this:

```
<users>
    <user id="123456" nick="nickname" done="false" />
  </users>
  <machines>
    <machine id="123" sd="123" ref="" done="false" />
    <machine id="456" sd="456" ref="" done="false" />
    <machine id="789" sd="789" ref="" done="false" />
  </machines>
</order>
```

This is my code which doesn't work:

```
XmlDocument doc = XmlDocument.Load(path);
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("users");
                    foreach(XmlNode node in nodes){
                        foreach(XmlAttribute attribute in node.Attributes){
                            if(attribute.Name== "id" && attribute.Value == "102030"){
                                node.RemoveAll();
                            }
                        }
                    }
doc.Save(path);
```

I am a newbie in C# so I need every help!

Thanks in advance, geibi

Comment: Did my answer help @geibi02?

Answer (score 1):

[`XmlNode.RemoveAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.removeall?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlNode_RemoveAll) does **not** remove a node. Instead it:

> Removes all the child nodes and/or attributes of the current node.

Thus, instead you need to remove the `node` from its parent:

```
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```